# Getting multiplication of column values on a joined table based on condition

Tags: oracle, join

The title was best I could find to explain my question, I don't think it helps though. Anyways, I have two tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE YEARLY_RATES
 ( 
   RATE_YEAR NUMBER(4,0),
   RATE NUMBER(6,4)
 );

 CREATE TABLE PERSON_ACCOUNT
(
   PAID_YEAR NUMBER(4,0),
   PAID_AMOUNT(10,2)
);
```

I need to select PERSON_ACCOUNT.PAID_YEAR, PERSON_ACCOUNT.PAID_AMOUNT,PERSON_ACCOUNT.PAID_AMOUNT * multiplication of the YEARLY_RATES.RATE WHERE YEARLY_RATES.RATE_YEAR >= PERSON_ACCOUNT.PAID_YEAR. So for instance if I have the following data in PERSON_ACCOUNT

```
PAID_YEAR|PAID_AMOUNT
---------------------
   2006    2150.69
   2007    3290.40
   2008    3000.35
```

and YEARLY_RATES tables

```
RATE_YEAR|RATE
---------------------
   2006    1.067
   2007    1.208
   2008    1.057
```

then I should be able to have the following output:

```
PAID_YEAR|PAID_AMOUNT|INDEXED_AMOUNT
----------------------------------------------------
   2006    2150.69      2150.69*1.067*1.208*1.057
   2007    3290.40      3290.40*1.208*1.057 
   2008    3000.35      3000.35*1.057
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

```
   SELECT PA.PAID_YEAR,PA.PAID_AMOUNT,EXP(SUM(LN(YR.RATE)))*PA.PAID_AMOUNT
     FROM YEARLY_RATES YR, PERSON_ACCOUNT PA
     WHERE YR.RATE_YEAR>=PA.PAID_YEAR
     GROUP BY PA.PAID_YEAR,PA.PAID_AMOUNT
```

EXP(SUM(LN(YR.RATE)))  is just a trick to get the multiplication of the column values as there's no ready function available in Oracle.